# Only one file decrypting in for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, cryptography

I have an issue with my program.

Whenever I encrypt multiple files, it works flawlessly; when I decrypt the files however, it fails pretty hard. No errors or anything.
The issue is just;

Only one file decrypts, no more. The rest of the files do look decrypted, but at the same time ?not?

Here is an example image of what shows when I decrypted a text file with pi to 1m digits. This only happens when decrypting multiple files.
[image]

Finally, here is the code. Big thanks to anyone willing to be helpfull!!! :)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
import os
import sys
import os.path
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from os import startfile

# Just some path defining stuff
user_profile = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
user_desktop = user_profile + "\\Documents"    

os.chdir(sys.path[0]) 

    
save_path = f'{sys.path[0]}/TestEncrypted'.replace("\\","/")
save_path2 = f'{sys.path[0]}/TestDecrypted'.replace("\\","/")

# Create directories for encrypted/decrypted files
try:
    os.mkdir(save_path)
except:
    print(f'Directory: {save_path} already exists')
try:
    os.mkdir(save_path2)
except:
    print(f'Directory: {save_path2} already exists')

def padkey(key):
    global oldkey
    oldkey = key
    while len(key)% 16 != 0:
        key+= " "
    return key

def encrypt1():
    """
    Loops over files for encryption.
    """
    newkey = padkey('testpass').encode('UTF-8')
    cipher = AES.new(newkey,AES.MODE_CBC)
    # Create for loop here!!!
    filez = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose files to encrypt',initialdir = user_desktop)
    for filename in filez:
        try:
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                rfile = f.read()
            f.close()
        except:
            messagebox.showerror("ITExtra Popup", "You didn't select a file")
        ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(rfile, AES.block_size))
        encryptfilename = filename.split('/')[-1]+'.ENCRYPTED'
        completeName = os.path.join(save_path, encryptfilename).replace("\\","/")
        print(completeName)
        with open(completeName,'wb') as c_file:
            c_file.write(cipher.iv)
            c_file.write(ciphertext)
        c_file.close()
        label2=Label(root,text=(save_path+"/"+encryptfilename).replace('\\','/').lower(),font='Helvetica 13 bold italic',fg='BLUE',bg='black').place(relx=0,rely=0.88)
    return

def decrypt1():
    """
    Loops over files for decryption.
    """
    
    faildec = 0
    succdec = 0

    filez2 = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose files to decrypt',initialdir = save_path)
    for decryptfilename in filez2:
        newkey = padkey('testpass').encode('UTF-8')
        # Decrypt file
        try:
            with open(decryptfilename,'rb') as c_file:
                iv = c_file.read(16)
                ciphertext = c_file.read()
            c_file.close()
        except:
            faildec +=1
        cipher = AES.new(newkey,AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        rfile = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext),AES.block_size)
        
        # Input extension and save file
        filename = decryptfilename.split('/')[-1].replace('.ENCRYPTED', '')
        completeName2 = os.path.join(save_path2, filename)
        with open(completeName2, 'wb') as writefile:
            writefile.write(rfile)
        writefile.close()

        label2=Label(root,text=(save_path2+"/"+filename).replace("\\","/").lower(),font='Helvetica 10 bold italic',fg='BLUE',bg='black').place(relx=0,rely=0.88)
        succdec +=1
    response2 = messagebox.askyesno("ITExtra Popup", f"""Do you want to open the 'Decrypted' directory?\n{save_path2}

Successful decryptions  = {succdec}
Failed decryptions      = {faildec} 
""")
    if response2 == 1:
        startfile(save_path2)
    return

print(sys.path[0])
print(save_path)
print(save_path2)
print(user_desktop)

root = Tk()

w = 850 # width for the Tk root
h = 310 # height for the Tk root
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/3) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

frame1=LabelFrame(root,bd=0,bg='#000000')
but1 = Button(frame1, text="ENCRYPT file", padx=30, pady=10, bg="#1f1f1f",fg="red",font='Helvetica 15 bold', command=encrypt1,relief=FLAT)
but2 = Button(frame1, text="DECRYPT file", padx=30, pady=10, bg="#1f1f1f",fg="green",font='Helvetica 15 bold', command=decrypt1,relief=FLAT)
but1.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=1,pady=5)                 # Encrypt FILE          #
but2.grid(row=2,column=2,pady=5)                        # Decrypt FILE          #
frame1.place(relx=0.20,rely=0.5)
    
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**
Removed except statements for debugging purposes.

Comment: I tried adding ```rfile.decode('UTF-8')``` in the decryption function. This however did not work also. Made a comment in main post to show position of ```rfile.decode('UTF-8')```

Comment: Generally using a blanket `except` statement can be dangerous, because this will catch any error. What errors are you expecting to catch in each of your try except blocks?

Comment: Most things don't error. The errors I'm trying to catch with ```Except``` are when the user doest select a file for example. Or when the user enters a right password for /most/ files, except for some, it will error. But I still want the loop to keep going in case there are files after the one that error'd. It did error when I tried converting the ```rfile``` to ```utf-8```

Comment: The problem is you are not creating a new cipher instance for each file during encryption, instead you are creating a single cipher instance before the file loop and reusing it for each encrypted file. The actual IV used is thus the last block of ciphertext from the previous files. The `.iv` property of the cipher object is not kept updated, it just the initial IV supplied to the instance.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, so I can vote it as such. Thank you my friend! Just seemed a bit unintuitive as the password stayed the same, so I didn't think the cypher would change.